# Failed to start the Kernel in Jupyter Notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, jupyter

I tried running the notebook in VS Code in M1 MacBook Air.But ended up with this error:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akshitdudeja/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.6.1201981810/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/jupyter_daemon.py", line 158, in _start_notebook
    from notebook import notebookapp as app
  File "/Users/akshitdudeja/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 57, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)
ImportError: The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have 4.5.3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akshitdudeja/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.6.1201981810/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/daemon/daemon_python.py", line 54, in _decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/akshitdudeja/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.6.1201981810/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/jupyter_daemon.py", line 111, in m_exec_module_observable
    self._start_notebook(args, cwd, env)
  File "/Users/akshitdudeja/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.6.1201981810/pythonFiles/vscode_datascience_helpers/jupyter_daemon.py", line 160, in _start_notebook
    from notebook import app as app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'notebook' (/Users/akshitdudeja/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py)

Failed to run jupyter as observable with args notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="/Users/akshitdudeja/VS Code/ML/Scikit Learn/Archive/titanic" --config=/var/folders/x7/p_lhpn8162g973v2nq2lmwyh0000gn/T/363e7ce2-17bc-4e69-89f3-87611ae3e03a/jupyter_notebook_config.py --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to update jupyter by using the following command:

   `pip install -U jupyter`
2. 

> ImportError(("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)

you could try the following to upgrade tornado

`pip install tornado --upgrade`